# How pass a 0 in $atts?

Tags: array

I need to pass an attribute (tabindex="0") into my navigation link. I use this filter:

```
/**
 * Add tabindex attribute to menu links
 *
 * Brings keyboard accessibility for opera browser.
 */
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'atts_menu_tabindex' );
function atts_menu_tabindex( $atts, $item, $args )
{
    $atts['tabindex'] = 0;
    return $atts;
}
```

This filter works fine with all values unless with ***0*** (zero). What can i do, to pass the "0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because WP checks the value with `empty()`:

```
if ( ! empty( $value ) )
```

… and `empty()` is `TRUE` for values like `0` or `"0"`.

You have two options now:

1. Filter `walker_nav_menu_start_el` and replace `<a` with `<a tabindex=0`.
2. Pass `$atts['tabindex'] = "0 ";` in your original function. Note the extra space. It circumvents the `empty` check. Test it with different browsers.

Comment: Oh dynamic typing how we love and hate thee.